# Why does profiler reads always higher on first execution and how to decrease it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, profiler

I had created the following table and inserted 20K records by executing the following statements:

```
create table Testing
(
col1 int,
col2 varchar(50),
col3 bit,
col4 int,
col5 varchar(50),
col6 bit);

declare 
@flag bit = 1,
@count int

while @flag = 1
    begin
        set @count = (Select count(*) from Testing);
        if (@count = 20000)
            begin
                set @flag = 0;
            end
        else
            begin
                insert into Testing values(100, 'Testing', 1, 100, 'Testing', 1)
            end
    end
```

And then executed the following query 6 times:

```
select * from testing
where col2 = 'Testing'
```

The profiler shows 276 reads for the first execution and 135 for the rest of five.

[image]

I don't know why it's taking high reads on first time and how to decrease the reads for the first time.

**Note:** I had executed DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS; DBCC FREEPROCCACHE; before each execution.

Comment: First time it has to read the pages from disk. You might get a better result if you have an index on col2. Inspect the execution plan for that.

Comment: I had cleared the buffer and cache every time before executing.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think if you make it a stored procedure it might be faster the first time it's hit. I think the execution plans are cashed or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a similar pattern here. In my case the first batch shows up as 226 reads and subsequent reads as 105.

The first time you execute the query after creating and populating the table it automatically creates statistics on `col2` in order to get an estimated number of rows.

If you add the `SP:StmtCompleted` event to the trace you can see that this is responsible for the extra reads that the first batch encounters.

[image: Profiler]

To answer the question "how to decrease the reads for the first time?" technically you could disable automatic statistics creation but **you shouldn't do this** the overhead of automatic statistics maintenance is generally nothing when compared to the benefit of more accurate cardinality estimates and better query plans.

Comment: @Prakash - It isn't time related. The first time you run a query on that table with a where clause such as `where col2 = 'Testing'` and  SQL Server doesn't find any statistics it will automatically create statistics on that column. They will get auto updated as well according to number of changes to column values. See the Stale Statistics section [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293623.aspx) for more about auto updates.

Comment: I don't want to disable automatic statistics creation. But what I'm seeking for a way to decrease the reads as many as I can.

Comment: @Prakash - Why? As a goal in itself it is pointless. You now understand what is causing them. Have you any evidence they are causing problems? If you want to optimise the specific query in the question generally speaking you could add an index but that would do nothing in this case as 100% of the rows match.

Comment: Yes, they are affecting the performance for the first time. I will soon update the question with some examples.

Comment: Or on the second thought I will ask a new question for the performance issue because that will be off topic. So let's close this matter here. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @Prakash I agree that would be wandering off from the original question. I'll keep an eye out for the new one.

Comment: Can this difference fluctuate? e.g. 102, 6, 276, 75, 125 (the fluctuation range). And if yes then what should I consider as basic reads?

Comment: @Prakash - Yes it can fluctuate. If you were to take the database offline and then put it online again then the initial reads for the batch will be higher again as it needs to load the object metadata. The reads reported by `STATISTICS IO` should not fluctuate as much, if at all, though and will be better to look at as those are the reads that you can actually control by query tuning.

Comment: If a query takes [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291779/low-statistics-logical-reads-and-high-profiler-reads) much difference then how can I take STATISTICS IO as my base. Please also check out this [post](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic612956-65-1.aspx#bm612975)  something same is happening with me.

Comment: @Prakash - The reads may or may not be a problem. If you consistently notice a large discrepancy between the two then it may be an indication that your query is using scalar UDFs for example. Fluctuations of a few hundred are unlikely to make any significant difference though. There is much more to query tuning than just focusing on that number in isolation.

Comment: I agree with **There is much more to query tuning** but reads play the key role in my case.